# Can my dSLR add a signature or watermark without post-processing?

Tags: digital, slr, watermark

Is it possible add signature or water mark on photographs without post-processing? Like add the signature/water mark while capturing the photos. Any settings available?

Comment: Yes depending on what camera you have. Did you read the manual?

Comment: If you're asking about *your* DLSR, it'd probably help if you mention the make and model.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. Cameras don't generally have this feature built in, however there are ways of automating post processing tasks so that watermarks are applied when software downloads the image without the user having to perform any extra steps, it just depends what software you have

Comment: The question asked is it possible, I suggest it isn't because cameras don't do that, and I suggest an alternative.

Comment: Not true, it's been done: http://www.ws.binghamton.edu/fridrich/Research/DFRWSfinal.pdf though I will admit that it's unlikely that the OP has a camera with a similar feature.

Comment: lol, ok I admit that I generalised when i said "cameras don't generally have this feature". Looks like it was done once. Looks like it was about 12 years ago judging by the research references. As requirements go probably completely unnecessary. If you want a watermark for evidence purposes then you change the date/time settings in the camera, negating the usefulness of the concept

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** Although, as mentioned most cameras will require some modification.

### With a Physical Mask

The low pass filter on the sensor could be augmented to cast a shadow on the sensor. The easiest way I could imagine doing this would be a metal vapor deposition onto the glass followed by a photolithography and etching process to remove the undesired metal. The resulting shadow mask will add a watermark to each image the camera produces.

An additional benefit of this method is that it can also be used on a film camera.

Comment: Wait, where would this shadow mask go in a film camera?

Comment: Right in front of the film, it would only work well with small aperture.

Comment: I was thinking more of how you used to get dates on cameras with some sort of light source through a stencil.